# How can I make a local drive visible to a Windows XP VMWare image?

Tags: vmware

How can I make a local drive visible to a Windows XP VMWare image?

Preferably, I'd like to make local drives available as Drive Letters within the VM Ware Image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If both OSs are windows:

```
vm > settings > options > shared folders
```

That way you can map a drive in the virtual machine as a folder on the host. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use samba (linux host) or sharing (windows host), then map them as network drives on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really make the drive visible (e.g to use gparted etc.), and not just copy some files:

You can create a pseudo-vmdk that will in fact be a link to an existing physical drive ( or one/more of its partitions)
The command is e.g.

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename mydrive.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

This maps the first physical drive as a whole.
You have to run this as root/admin (for win7 start a cmd.exe as admin, and cd to the directory where you have vmware)

(To map partitions3,4 only:  -partitions 3,4)

Then map the vmdk to a drive in the vm, and presto!

Answer (score 0):

vm > settings > options > shared folders > In this tab you can choose which way it will work. Even do mapping!

Comment: Repeating the same content as another answer adds nothing of value.